# how to pass file path in run time in sql statement using C programming

Tags: c++, mysql, c, sqlite

I am trying to merge two SQL databases with same schema using C programming. As I am new to SQL, I tried the below code to merge using C programming. 
But I could not merge it as I could not pass the file path in the sql statement in runtime. How to pass the file path in the below sql statement so that I can merge.

/*Create SQL statement to merge two DBs*/

```
        rc = sqlite3_open(argv[1], &db); /*-----> argv[1] is old_student.db*/
        if( rc )
        {
            printf("Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Opened database successfully\n");
        }
        /*Create SQL statement to merge two DBs*/
        sql = "attach '<file_path_name>' as toMerge;\ /*--------> how to pass file path here in runtime */
               BEGIN;\
               insert or ignore into student_table (Name, AGE, Address)\
               select Name, AGE, Address from toMerge.student_table;\
               COMMIT;";
        /* Execute SQL statement */
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
        if( rc != SQLITE_OK )
        {
            printf("SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
            sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s merged New_student.db successfully with old_student.db\n");
        }
        sqlite3_close(db);
```

Please let me know how should i pass the parameter in SQL statement in runtime. 
Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by declaring the `sql` array as a [VLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), and then using `sprintf` to construct the query as shown below.

```
static const char *prefix = "attach '";
static const char *suffix =
  "' as toMerge;"
  " BEGIN;"
  " insert or ignore into student_table (Name, AGE, Address)"
  " select Name, AGE, Address from toMerge.student_table;"
  " COMMIT;";

int length = strlen(prefix) + strlen(argv[1]) + strlen(suffix) + 1;
char sql[length];
sprintf( sql, "%s%s%s", prefix, argv[1], suffix );
```